# My Reactjs program keeps executing the useEffect hook continuously, whilst I want it to execute only once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useHttp from "./hooks/use-http";

export default function App() {
  const getReq = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "" // assume this to be a random link fetching data
    );
    const responseData = await response.json();
    return responseData;
  };

  const { sendRequest, data } = useHttp(getReq);

  useEffect(() => {
    sendRequest();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useHttp = (getReq) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const sendRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getReq();
      setData(data);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  return {
    sendRequest,
    data,
  };
};

export default useHttp;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In the useEffect hook, if I remove sendRequest as a dependency (as done in this example), I don't get any problems and the hook only runs once.

But, if I add it as a dependency (for good practice purposes), the hook runs continuously and I get recurring console.log statements. Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried `useCallback`? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: @Darius, I  added a console.log function to the useEffect hook, but the function is only being called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, if I add it as a dependency (for good practice purposes), the
> hook runs continuously and I get recurring console.log statements.
> Could someone please explain why this is happening?

Because `sendRequest` is a function which is re created each time the component is re-rendered, hence, it is different on each render. Because of that, when it is listed as a dependency, `useEffect` re-runs. Consider using `useCallback` and wrapping `sendRequest` using it.

---

Consider re-rendering of a component same as the function being re-invoked, hence you are creating all the variables or functions inside it from scratch (except cases when React takes care to retain value of your variable across re-renders; this happens with variables from state for example).

Comment: Thanks for the solution guys! Here's what happened after I implemented the useCallback function: Suprisingly, I still kept getting the same multiple rendering problem, and now, only way to solve this was to remove the dependencies from either the useCallback function, or the useEffect function (as before). I quickly realised the problem was in the getReq() function, which was probably re-rendering and hence triggered the render chain. To fix this, I moved getReq() to another file and passed a pointer to that function via import statement. Am I right in assuming the problem was in the getReq Fn

Comment: I thought you added sendRequest as a dependency. Anyway both sendRequest and getReq are re-created on each render, so if you put them in dependencies, useEffect will run each time. That is why when you declare function outside your component (like you did), it will be same on each render, so you can put it as dependency. But I think it is not needed because it won't refer to anything from component scope. Sometimes you can't do that and then you can look into useCallback.