# useEffect keeps rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, use-effect

In a react app, when creating a component, I use useEffect to handle a HTTP request via a custom hook (which fetch via a useCallback). Then, to parse the parameters for the request, I have a layer for services which return the expected values.

As a result, this workflow keeps re-rendering in a loop and the apps gets stacked.

Component:

```js
  import React, { Fragment, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { getProject } from '../../../services/Project.service';
import { AuthContext } from '../../../shared/context/auth.context';
import { NavOptions } from '../../../shared/constants/NavOptions';
import { useHttpClient } from '../../../shared/hooks/http.hook';

import SideNavigation from '../../../shared/components/Navigation/SideNavigation/SideNavigation';
import NavLinks from '../../../shared/components/Navigation/NavLinks/NavLinks';

import './Dashboard.css';

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  console.log('Dashboard...');
  
  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const [project, setProject] = useState();
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  
  const projectId = useParams().projectId;

  
  const getProject = async () => {
    console.log('getProject...');
    
    console.log('auth', auth.token);

    const response = await sendRequest(getProject(projectId, auth.token));

    if (response.status === 201) {
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log('project:', responseData);
      setProject(responseData);
    } else {
      console.log('getting buildings failed!');
      const error = await response.json();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    projectId && getProject();
  }, []);

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  let content = (
    <div className="bim-y-dashboard">
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SideNavigation>
        <NavLinks options={NavOptions.PROJECT} projectId />
      </SideNavigation>
      <MainContent>{content}</MainContent>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Custom hook:

```js
  
  export const useHttpClient = () => {
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  const activeHttpRequests = useRef([]);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(
    async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
      console.log('sendRequest...');  

      console.log('url', url);
      console.log('method', method);
      console.log('body', body);
      console.log('headers', headers);
    },[]);

  const clearError = () => {
    setError(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      activeHttpRequests.current.forEach(abortCtrl => abortCtrl.abort());
    };
  }, []);

  return { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError };
};
```

Service:

```js
export const getProject = (projectId, token) => {
  console.log('getProject...');
  return (`/projects/id/${projectId}`, 'GET', null, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
  });
}
```

What am I missing to avoid this constant re-rendering?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my opinion you don't have clean codes for this feature... why do you pass async method as a argument to custom hook?

Comment: HI @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh , because there is fetch request later. Where do you see I do not have clean code? I am trying to split all the responsibilities from the rendering to the request.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling your issue is in code you have not shared, as the above looks legit.

Things you can try:

- Comment out `const auth = useContext(AuthContext);` in your custom hook to make sure the culprit is not in your context
- Make sure `const response = await sendRequest(..)` returns what you are expecting
- Add a new hook, something like `const [data, setData] = useState(null)`, then after you get a response, set it in your hook `setData(response)`
- Finally, in your `useEffect`, update your condition as `projectId && !data && getProject();`

That will ensure your re rendering issue is neither on your auth context nor in your fetch request.

Hope that helps; if not, please update the question with the full code of your component and I'll take a second look :)

Comment: hi,

As you can see, there is not such a big difference. Trying to isolate the scenario.

Comment: You are still not sharing the full component. You have a `project` useState hook but it's not used anywhere; Can you share how that's used? Also please follow the suggestion above and let me know if that helped; We can go further from there

Comment: Indeed! you are right! there is not much more!

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVED**:

Found this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559763/my-reactjs-program-keeps-executing-the-useeffect-hook-continuously-whilst-i-wan)

It explains that because of sendRequest method, it keeps re-rendering.